# Binding a comma separated list to a List<int> in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

The default binder in web api expecst

http://url.com/webapi/Report/?PageIds=3243&PageIds=2365

To bind to

```
public IHttpActionResult Report(List<int> PageIds){ // exciting webapi code}
```

I wish to bind
http://url.com/webapi/Report/?PageIds=3243,2365

as I am running out of space in my URL to do a `GET`.

I have created a class
 public class CommaSeparatedModelBinder :

```
System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder
    {
        public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
           //Binding in here
        }
     }
```

and registered this in my `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
 var provider = new SimpleModelBinderProvider(
           typeof(List<int>), new CommaSeparatedModelBinder());
            config.Services.Insert(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), 0, provider);
```

I have altered my method signature to use the model binder like so

```
 public IHttpActionResult Report( [ModelBinder] List<int> PageIds){ // exciting webapi code}
```

However a break point in my binder is not being hit (and the list does not get bound).

What else do I need to configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to follow *all* of the steps in this article: [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

It appears you are missing the last step:

> With a model-binding provider, you still need to add the [ModelBinder] attribute to the parameter, to tell Web API that it should use a model binder and not a media-type formatter. But now you don’t need to specify the type of model binder in the attribute:
>
> ```
>    public HttpResponseMessage Get([ModelBinder] GeoPoint location) { ... }
> ```

Also, I've never tried binding to `List<int>`. You may not be able to model bind to it because it is a build-in type. If so, just box it with a custom class type and make sure to add the `[ModelBinder]` attribute to the class.

OR....

A better solution: KISS

```
public IHttpActionResult Report(string PageIds)
{
     var ids = PageIds.Split(',');
     // exciting web api code and/or more robust checking of the split
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I did not miss that step... just missed putting it in my question :) see the edit! I will try the box and the fallback which I admit had not occurred to me! I prefer to keep things strongly typed if possible!