# How to pass multiple parameters to Get Method and Route them in .NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm making a (restful) Web API in .NET Core and stumbled among some problems.

I cannot seem to find how to pass multiple subscription ID's... **I need to be able to show multiple periods(invoices) of multiple subscriptions.**

My route at the moment is 
[Route("tenants/{tenantId:long}/subscriptions/{subscriptionId:long}/invoices/{invoiceId:long}/categories")]

From this way it seems impossible for me to pass more subscription IDs.
Some terms I found but not fully understand are:

- Model Binding
- **[FromQuery]**

My classes:

```
    public class Subscription
    {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Invoice
    {
    public long SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public long PortalId { get; set; }
    }
```

My controllers with routes `[Route("tenants/{tenantId:long}/subscriptions")]` and `[Route("tenants/{tenantId:long}/subscriptions/{subscriptionId:long}/invoices")]`

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<SubscriptionViewModel> Find(long tenantId)
    {
        var subscriptionList = _subscriptionManager.Find(tenantId);
        ...
        return subscriptionViewModels;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<InvoiceViewModel> Find(long subscriptionId)
    {
        var invoiceList = _invoiceManager.Find(subscriptionId);
        ...
        return invoiceViewModels;
    }
```

- Please note that i'm using a **Mapper** for my data (which is why i'm using ViewModels).
- The currently written code is for a specific subscription.

I am looking for a Route like **/api/invoices?subscriptionId=x,y,z**

I understand(?) I need the [FromQuery] for that, but I cannot seem to find out how, especially if my parameter (subscriptionId) stays the same.

Comment: It might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217534/how-to-send-a-list-of-integers-to-web-api-2-get-request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the requirement which you have mentioned as:

> I am looking for a Route like /api/invoices?subscriptionId=x,y,z

You can do couple of things:

1. pass the subscriptionIds one after the other separated by `&` in the query string of the URL and change the input parameter of action method to accept array of subscriptionIds
   example of route:

```
/api/invoices/find?subscriptionId=x&subscriptionId=y&subscriptionId=z
```

example of action method parameter accepting array of subscriptionIds:

```
public IEnumerable<InvoiceViewModel> Find([FromQuery]long[] subscriptionId)
```

2. pass the comma separated string as querystring in the URL and write a piece of logic in the action method to split the string based on comma to get an array of subscriptionIds
   example of route:

```
/api/invoices/find?subscriptionIds=x,y,z
```

example of action method:

```
public IEnumerable<InvoiceViewModel> Find([FromQuery]string subscriptionIds)
{
    var ids = subscriptionIds.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    // do the logic on multiple subscriptionIds
}
```

Apart from this, you can go for creating custom model binders as well as suggested in other answers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If it helps, please mark the answer with the tick. Thanks

Comment: Solution No2 is a very poor design for an API endpoint, both technically and semantically.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a specific Request view model which accepts a collection of invoice ids:

```
public class InvoiceRequestModel
{
    IEnumerable<long> InvoiceIDS { get; set; }
}
```

and use it for your action method:

```
[Route("tenants/{tenantId:long}/subscriptions/{subscriptionId:long}/invoices")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<InvoiceViewModel> Get(InvoiceRequestModel requestModel)
{

}
```

---

In the case you want to use query parameters, mark your action parameter with the `[FromQuery]` attribute:

```
[Route("tenants/{tenantId:long}/subscriptions/{subscriptionId:long}/invoices")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<InvoiceViewModel> Get([FromQuery]IEnumerable<long> invoiceIDs)
{

}
```

and on creating the request, pass each value with the same key in the query string:

```
invoiceIDs=1&invoiceIDs=2&invoiceIDs=3
```

Finally, it will look like this:

```
tenants/{tenantId}/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/invoices?invoiceIDs=1&invoiceIDs=2&invoiceIDs=3
```

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try this if other methods dont work but I prefer not to make a specific ViewModel. Thanks!

Comment: @NielsSchepers Creating a RequestModel is a best practice. Do you have any reasoning not to?

Comment: My project is completely mapped and i'm trying to keep the modelviews mapped. Which means if I add another ModelView there is nowhere to map it to (which is obviously the purpose), but unless I really have to, i'm trying to avoid making extra models. I will definetely keep this method in mind, it was something I didnt think of before. EDit : i'm pretty sure this is the most correct fix, dont get me wrong!

Answer (score 1):

There can be many ways to achieve this task (I can think of two-three for now).

1) instead of long subscriptionid take a string as an input and validate it before proceeding further.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<InvoiceViewModel> Find(string subscriptionIds)
{
    var list = validateInput(subscriptionIds);
    var invoiceList = _invoiceManager.FindList(list);
    ...
    return invoiceViewModels;
}

public IList<long> validateInput(string subscriptionIds)
{
    var list = subscriptionIds.Split(",");
    ... // Code to convert each element in long and throw if it is not long
    return longlist;
}
```

2) Create custom model binders.

Steps are mentioned here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

=> [FromUri] attribute can be used to bind the Complex types from query string parameters but i am not sure how i would use that.

If you ask me, i would go for approach-1 (not to increase complexity).

Comment: Thank you Vijay. Pretty similar to the 1st anwser, I think I know how to fix it now!